# pytest fixture in setup_method

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a `function` scoped fixture.

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def some_fixture(req):
    print "This is not the end"
    return "okay"
```

Is it possible to invoke the fixture in the `setup_method` somehow.?

Something like the following snippet...

```
class TestOne(object):
    def setup_method(self, method, some_fixture): # this would give argument error
        print "okay"

    def test_one(self):
        pass
```

I know fixture would work same as setup_method, but I have got a very corner case scenario and I want the fixture to be executed in setup_method itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark your setup_method as fixture & then call it in your tests.

```
class TestOne(object):

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def setup_method(self, method, some_fixture): # this would give argument error
        print "okay"

    def test_one(self, setup_method):
        pass
```

Comment: One enhancement, we can add the attribute `autouse=True` in the fixture and it will work same as setup_method of class. With that change, we won't have to mention setup_method as an argument in each and every test case. @Amit, please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.